# Sharepoint 2010 advanced search, appened to Keyword Query

Tags: search

I am hoping to append 'AND myValue' to the end of all searches which come from the advanced search box webpart. So far I have added a content editor & have been trying to append/alter values on page via jQuery. I have also tried to append k=AND myValue to the url of the page but so far no success. Is there any way to do this without creating a custom solution webpart?

Comment: I don't know your exact scenario, but defining a Search Scope and reconfiguring your advanced search web part might be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by overriding the preexisting JavaScript function which is responsible for the redirect. The order of events in javascript is as follows

```
 SearchButtonOnClick() {
     ResetPageHashCode();
     DoAdvancedSearch(.......);
 }
 DoAdvancedSeach(....){
          //A bunch of validation logic & conditions here

          var url = TargetPage+" ?k= "+QueryValue;
          NavigateTo(url);
     }
 }

//ADD FOLLOWING FUNCTION TO CONTENT EDITOR
function navigateTo(url) 
{
   // YOUR CHANGE TO 'url' HERE
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   if(!a.click) 
   { 
      window.location = url;
      return;
   }

   a.setAttribute('href', url);
   a.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(a); 
   a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried to append k=AND myValue to the url of the page

Have you tried using "Value of a parameter from URL" as a Keyword filter in Search Results web part?

*Since i cannot comment, i am forced to answer this way. sorry about that.*

Comment: No need to be sorry, but if you add details about how to do what you propose this do qualify as an answer :)